# PHP MySQL can't write on table

Tags: php, mysql, database

While the request completes without an error it doesn't write in the database. 
It connects to the database i've checked it.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("config.json"), true);
$dbuser = $json['dbuser'];
$servername = $json['dbip'];
$dbpass = $json['dbpass'];
$dbname = $json['dbname'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$email = $_GET['email'];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db( $dbname );

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO credentials (usermail, pass)
VALUES ($email, $password)";

?>
```

Example: `http://localhost/php/database.php?email=random@mail.com&password=ilovestackoverflow`

It just doesn't do anything. Please if you have any ideas

Comment: Hopefully you are not using this code anywhere, it's very hack-freindly. You should not pass user/pass with `$_GET`. `mysql_` is removed from the new PHP, and your statement is injection-prone: `"INSERT INTO credentials (usermail, pass)
VALUES ($email, $password)";`

Comment: @Rasclatt Thank for the note.

Comment: Use `$_POST`, look at `PDO` or `mysqli_`, once using a new db library, prepare/bind your user input.

Comment: Solved thank you for the notes again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must quote strings like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO credentials (usermail, pass)
VALUES ('$email', '$password')";
```

Comment: there is no **mysqli_query($conn,$sql);** at the end

Comment: Solved! Thank you :)